# Can we all stop posting duplicate questions about the Heartbleed bug?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed 9/10 posts appear to be about the [heartbleed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed) vulnerability, and most of them seem to be duplicate questions. Please, search for existing answers to your question before you ask it, leaving room for other topics!

Comment: I'm so very tempted to make a duplicate post of this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's nice to see when the news hits that new people are interested and come to the site to learn more. However, I doubt many of the new visitors really get how the site works; in the past few weeks I have been seeing a lot more low quality first posts as well.

Maybe for something like Heartbleed SEC.SE could put up a banner or link at the top "Have questions about the recent Heartbleed news?" to grab the attention of people who are just stopping by the website because of the news. However, in general it may be hard to determine how and when to use such a banner and how to moderate it, but it could be a cool feature which may also make sense on other SE network sites.

Comment: +1 Nice idea. I think this could be definitely implemented on other sites as well